# New tag request: binary repository manager

Tags: discussion, tags

We talk about all possible DevOps tools using their product names but at least in the case of the *Ivy/Artifactory/Nexus*.. product family there is a term I find descriptive and neutral enough:

> A *binary repository manager* is a software tool designed to optimize
>   the download and storage of binary files used and produced in software
>   development. (From [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_repository_manager))

What about introducing a corresponding tag?